# bpy.ops.object.location_clear() Does not clear locations for keyframe'd objects

Tags: python, scripting, objects, transforms

I'm trying to get all the meshes in a scene to their identity transform to export them so I can use their matrix_world to position them properly for animations/instancing/etc. I set them all back to their identity transform by clearing location/rotation/scale with `bpy.ops.object.(location|rotation|scale)_clear()`. However in the case of animated objects with keyframes their position doesn't get cleared, so they're exported incorrectly.

What's odd is that just doing ALT-(G|R|S) to clear them manually does clear the position properly. Is there something extra I need to do to properly clear the positions from Python?

My script is essentially just:

```
# Select all the objects we want to export and save
# their matrix_world so we can restore it after exporting

# Clear positions for exporting everything at its identity transform
bpy.ops.object.location_clear()
bpy.ops.object.rotation_clear()
bpy.ops.object.scale_clear()

# Export meshes to OBJ
bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(...)

# Restore transformations by setting matrix_world back to what we saved earlier
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to zeffii on the #blenderpython IRC channel on freenode I've got this sorted out. The issue is that the keyframes take precedence over the plain matrix_world so clearing it has no effect from the script. The solution is to mute the animation before clearing the transform, then un-mute it to restore the animation to how it was previously.

So the final script ends up basically like this:

```
# Select all the objects we want to export and save
# their matrix_world so we can restore it after exporting
# If the object is animated also mute keyframe animation so
# it doesn't block *_clear
for curve in obj.animation_data.action.fcurves:
    curve.mute = True

# Clear positions for exporting everything at its identity transform
bpy.ops.object.location_clear()
bpy.ops.object.rotation_clear()
bpy.ops.object.scale_clear()

# Export meshes to OBJ
bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(...)

# Restore transformations by setting matrix_world back to what we saved earlier
# If the object is animated also unmute keyframe animation to restore it
for curve in obj.animation_data.action.fcurves:
    curve.mute = False
```